# Communicate two IVR application

Tags: tcl, cisco, ivr, vxml, cisco-jtapi

I'm trying to communicate two IVR application with each other . One of them is caller , the other is called. This idea for the test autimation on ivr flows . But there is an issue on when receiver IVR asks for an input which has only DTMF options , i need to send DTMF caller to called .

Is there any way to make custom vxml element on cisco to send dtmf value or signal to the receiver.

Or any idea to do this job using tcl or something like.

All things will be helpfull , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you can make recordings of the tones and play them as audio files to the other system.

I say most because that won't work with many, newer sip connections that only support receiving tones via sip messages.

In that case, you can try to see if your ivr platform has any features outside of the standard that lets you transmit dtmf choices.

Comment: Hi Jim, 

Thanks for your answer , I sent DTMF tones as audio , and it worked .

Comment: Hello Jim , Can you help me about this issue ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658565/how-to-create-custom-send-dtmf-element-on-cvp-cisco